# How to loop through a array in beanshell script in jmeter 3.2

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Is it possible to loop through a array and select a character from the `passwd` using the `ord[i]` value? Code

```
             String ordinal = vars.get("ordinal");
             String[] ord = ordinal.split(",");
             log.info(ord[0]);

             String passwd = vars.get("password");
             requiredOrd = new ArrayList();
             for(int i=0; i< ord.length; i++)
             {

                    requiredOrd.add((passwd.charAt(ord[i])));

              }

          log.info(requiredOrd[0]);
```

Returns error message as follows:

2017-10-23 10:23:26,270 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `String ordinal = vars.get("ordinal"); String[] ord = ordinal.split(","); log.inf . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method charAt( java.lang.String ) not found in class'java.lang.String'
2017-10-23 10:23:26,270 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of:`String ordinal = vars.get("ordinal"); String[] ord = ordinal.split(","); log.inf . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method charAt( java.lang.String ) not found in class'java.lang.String'

Comment: Modified original code and and now include error message

Answer (score 0):

With Beanshell you can use String  method `charAt` which return character per index.

Index in array start with 0 so change to `i = 0` and `passwd.length()` call:

```
for(int i=0;i<passwd.length(); i++) {
  log.info(passwd.charAt(i))
```

Comment: The issue is that charAt method is not supported in jmeter. Therefore results in a error. Thank

Answer (score 0):

Since [JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for any form of scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) in JMeter so kindly consider switching to Groovy language as:

- it is more Java compliant
- it [has many enhancements on top of Java core SDK](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/)
- and [Groovy performance is much better being compared to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

The relevant code to iterate the String would be something like:

```
def password = 'foo'
for (char c : password.toCharArray()) {
    log.info('Current char: ' + c)
}
```

[image: JMeter Groovy Iterate String]

Comment: I used a workaround to bypass this, by disable the option for the ordinal. The ordinal setup is only required in a few scenarios and has been accepted.

Comment: I attempted to use the above code, which just outputs the list of all the password. I need to then get the character from the password based upon the the ord value. That is if, we get 1, 4,6 and a password = a234567, we should return  a, 4,6.

Answer (score 0):

> id_ALL="fbe9ca5c-942b-48d8-9ffd-5f92ae64437a",
>   "4f90ef0f-c317-47ea-9013-53729477c379",
>   "98fe94ae-7e1b-42bb-8c2f-cae0f31105a0",
>   "b3f8ed32-e273-41d8-8caf-2024feeccd8c"

```
StatusMFP_ALL="true","true","false","false"

StatusIwb_ALL= "true", "false", "false", "true"


String[] ids = {${id_ALL}};

String[] StatusM = {${StatusMFP_ALL}};

String[] StatusI = {${StatusIwb_ALL}};

//To get array length

int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("id_matchNr"));
log.info( "countest" + vars.get("id_matchNr"));

ArrayList c = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i <=count-1; i++)
       {
         String M=StatusM[i];
         String I=StatusI[i];
              if(M=="true" || I=="true" )      
                {                  
                    String x=ids[i];                
                    c.add(x);                                                                                                         
                }      
      }            
        for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) 
        {
              log.info(c.get(i));           
        }
        log.info(c.get(0));
```